# How to make background move infinitely?

Tags: css, animation, webkit

Let's say I have a repeating background of `pic.png`, like so...

```
body {
    background-image: url(pic.png);
}
```

I want to make it move *seamlessly* in a certain direction, say northeast at a given speed, **infinitely**. I've seen [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_anim_background-position) do it with animate, but that gradually slows and speeds up, not to mention move back and forth.

One more thing, (i think it automatically does this but i'll explain it), when it moves, I don't want to see the emptiness of white space, I want to see the background repeat with it *as it moves*.

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz Did you even *read* what's at that link you provided. Although MDN should be preferred w3schools is no longer the *complete* mess it was before,

Answer (score 3):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#55eb58488c64b5c4ef5b25a64a8c4f3b

Simple! Setup your background and give it an [animation property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

```
body {
  background-image: url("http://img15.deviantart.net/cafe/i/2012/085/2/8/orange_stripe_background_by_sonnywolfie-d4u0e93.png");
  background-size: 261px;
  animation: moveIt 10s linear infinite;
}
```

`animation: moveIt 10s linear infinite;`

I named my keyframe function moveIt.
The delay of the function is 10 seconds.
There are many values you can pass for the [animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) I just set mine to `linear` so my animation stays steady. Thus doesn't speed up or slow down at the end.

Then in your keyframe function you give it a name and set where and how

Now keyframe functions work by passing `to`, `from` or either percents %.

In this case I'm using `to` and `from` although `0%` and `100%` would work perfectly fine as well.

```
@keyframes moveIt {
  from {background-position: bottom left;}
  to {background-position: top right;}
}
```

**NOTE:** My [weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#e6c97963960da24e9da2306418c849af) uses [Prefix-free](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) that way you don't have to worry about vendor prefix's. However there is also [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) too which you may want to consider.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://img15.deviantart.net/cafe/i/2012/085/2/8/orange_stripe_background_by_sonnywolfie-d4u0e93.png");
  background-size: 261px;
  animation: moveIt 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes moveIt {
  from {background-position: bottom left;}
  to {background-position: top right;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is basically what you linked. You'll need a pattern image and then make the infinite animation, but move the background as many pixels as the dimentions of the image at keyframe 100%.

If your image is 32x32px and you want it to move up and right:

```
@keyframes mymove {
    100% {background-position: 32px -32px;}
}
```

You will also want to set the easing to linear to prevent the deceleration:

```
animation-timing-function: linear;
```